# Bluetooth private framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, iphone-privateapi, ios-bluetooth

I tried Bluetooth private framework to connect IOS with a non-ios device using BeeTee, but after pair successfully the device can not send / read data.

After a lot of search, I saw a sendMessage function in the RemoteDeviceManager.h, but looks like it does not work or I'm not using it well.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks and best regards,

Comment: What kind of BT device are you trying to connect to (exact version of BT layer and list of BT profiles you plan to use)?

Comment: Hi @RokJarc ! it's a custom device that uses Bluetooth 3.0, SSP and messaging protocol ;)

Comment: Hi @ llkoull i am unable to pair the Device using BeeTee app .how did you done .Can you please send any code to pair the devices.if it possible can you please share your email id.